# How css is applied to a class as well as ID?

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside a div and CSS is provided to the tr with id="test" is not getting updated, when css for td is removed it is working. How the element is selected in css and why style is not applied to the tr?

```css
#divID .w3-table #test {
  background-color: blue
}

#divID .w3-table td {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<div id="divID">
  <table class="w3-table">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="test">
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're applying the css to the TR not the TD, so the TD has a background colour as well and the TR's is no longer visible. I suggest doing somethingg as follows:

```
divID .w3-table td{background-color:yellow}
divID .w3-table #test td{background-color:blue}
```

In this case we add the #test (which targets the id of the tr) and then nest the td afterwards, this should ensure your css works as expected since your implementation targets the tr#test and the td is inside that #test still.

It is also better to but the #test later, so it also overrides by being last otherwise in theory the yellow colour could still be applied since it is defined later (override).

Answer (score 0):

**Method A)**

> `td` always overlay `tr`. **[**`#divID .w3-table td` always overlay `#divID .w3-table #test`**]**.

*Note* : `#test is Id for tr`.

**For fix:** you must insert `td` selector after `id` like this:

```
#divID .w3-table #test td {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```css
#divID .w3-table #test td {
  background-color: blue;
}

#divID .w3-table td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="divID">
  <table class="w3-table">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="test">
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

**Method B)**

You can use `:not` selector like this :

```
#divID .w3-table tr:not('#test') td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```css
#divID .w3-table tr:not('#test') td {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#divID .w3-table #test {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="divID">
  <table class="w3-table">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>    
    <tr id="test">
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```